# Primary kinetic isotope effect in the E1cB reaction

Tags: organic-chemistry

How is the primary [kinetic isotope effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kinetic_isotope_effect) (KIE) observed in the [E1cB reaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E1cB-elimination_reaction) when breaking of the $\ce{C}$-$\ce{H}$ bond is not the rate determining step of this reaction?

Comment: There is a section on Wikipedia describing KIEs in the E1cb reaction in quite some detail: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E1cB-elimination_reaction#Kinetic_isotope_effect Have you already seen that? Is there something specific you don't understand about it?

Comment: Is it like....1) A Deuterium 'Exchange' indicates that an E1CB REVERSIBLE reaction has taken place, & ...2) A beta deuterium substituted reactant showing primary kinetic isotopic effect indicates that an E1CB IRREVERSIBLE reaction has taken place? I'm confused. Please help.